# jQuery superfish menu :cursor issue

Tags: jquery, superfish

I am implementing the superfish menu and have noticed that there is a funny behavior with the cursor loosing its default styling (pointer).

For example:
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

If you rollover the first menu item and move your mouse over the drop down menu, the cursor changes from being a pointer to a regular arrow (I am using FF 3.5).

Has anyone else run into this / found a fix?

Comment: Using FF 3.5, I don't see that issue.

Comment: It does happen in 3.5 on the mac when you get several levels in on the menu and start moving your mouse around.

Comment: Yeah, this may be a mac only issue. Thanks for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to add some CSS that's attached to the list items as a work-around.

For example:

```
ul.myMenu li { cursor:pointer }
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you add

```
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```